# Powerpivot - Only Show Minimum Value

Tags: min, powerpivot

Newbie to DAX/PowerPivot and struggling with a specific problem.
I have a table

```
 Location  Category  Distance
 1         A         1.244
 2         A         2.111
 3         B         5.113
 4         C         0.124
 etc
```

I need to identify the Minimum distance out of the selection and only output for that record. So I'd have

```
Location  Category  Distance   MinDist
 1         A         1.244
 2         A         0.111     0.111
 3         B         5.113
 4         C         3.124
 etc
```

I've tried various measures but always end up with simply a repeat of the Distance column....whatever filters I try to apply. 
Please help.

Comment: What you are showing looks like a calculated column. Is that what you have tried? What measures have you tried? What is the end goal? will the measure be used in a pivot table? will it be used in another calculation?

Answer (score 1):

If your table was called 'table1' then this would give you the overall minimum:

```
=CALCULATE(MIN(Table1[Distance]), ALL(Table1))
```

Depending on your requirements, you may have to specify columns in the ALL() to reduce how much of the filter is opened up (suggest you research ALL() as it is a very important DAX function).

To return zero (blanks is tricky) for the non matchers you could package it in:

```
=
 IF (SUM ( Table1[Distance] ) = CALCULATE ( MIN ( Table1[Distance] ), ALL ( Table1 ) ),
          CALCULATE ( MIN ( Table1[Distance] ), ALL ( Table1 ) ),
          0
     )
```

Comment: I'd not written my original question clear enough and failed to mention I only wanted the minimum from the SELECTED locations in the pivot. However, your method put me on track and I simply used ALLSELECTED instead of ALL for the table and its done the trick....the non matchers code also worked (although I had to change the SUM to a MIN) Thanks